# Inline Assembly - AT&T Syntax - How to move to a variable

Tags: macos, assembly, inline-assembly, att

So I'm working on a code cave where I basically replace a call to _memcpy with my jump, and then I want to save what is in the source. Original assembly:

```
mov     [esp+8], edx    ; size
mov     [esp+4], eax    ; ptr to source
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
mov     [esp], eax      ; ptr to destination
call    _memcpy
```

I'm struggling w/the syntax of this for AT&T, basically I want to store [esp+8], [esp+4] and [esp] in my own variables.  I'm trying to do it this way:

```
void codecave_jump( void ) __attribute__ ( ( signal, naked ) );
void codecave_jump( void ){

    void *destination, *source;
    size_t size;

    // push all registers onto the stack
    __asm__("pushal\n\t");

    // get size
     __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl 8(%ecx), %0\n\t" : "=g" (size)
            );

    // get source
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl 4(%ecx), %0\n\t" : "=g" (source)
            );

    // get destination
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "movl %%eax, %0\n\t" : "=g" (destination)
            );

    // restore all of our registers
    __asm__("popal\n\t");

    // call memcpy
    __asm__("call __memcpy\n\t");

    // do the copy
    memcpy(destination, source, size);
}
```

And I'm getting the following error: 
error: operand number missing after %-letter
error: operand number missing after %-letter

Basically it's yelling at me for my:
"movl 8(%ecx), %0\n\t" : "=g" (size)

Does anyone know how I should be doing this properly in AT&T syntax?  I really miss the Intel syntax on OS X :/

Comment: immediate values uses $ not % like $0

Answer (score 2):

Since the resulting AT&T code uses percent signs for register names, you have to [use double percent signs](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#toc5) for register names when there are operands such as `size`:

```
"movl 8(%%ecx), %0\n\t" : "=g" (size)
```

It's similar to how you sometimes need double percent signs for `printf`.
Seems you got it right further down for `%%eax`, I'm guessing that line compiles fine.

---

There is no opcode for `mov mem32, mem32`. You would first need to move the data to a register, then move it to a memory location (just like the Intel version does for `destination`)

```
// get size
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "movl 8(%ecx), %eax\n\t"
    );
__asm__ __volatile__(
    "movl %%eax, %0\n\t" : "=g" (size)
    );
```

---

For the record: I also find AT&T syntax incredibly confusing. :)

Comment: I thought that as well :/  But then I get more errors:

/var/folders/b1/rl112vqd3c79nymwj8vnzv180000gn/T//cc1Lrc0i.s:585:too many memory references for `mov'
/var/folders/b1/rl112vqd3c79nymwj8vnzv180000gn/T//cc1Lrc0i.s:590:too many memory references for `mov'

Comment: Yes, there is no opcode for `mov mem32, mem32` so you will need to use a register for the move. I added a note about this.